# how to save selected value from dropdown in database as foreign key?

Tags: mysql, laravel, dropdown

I have subcategory table and its id is a foreign key in the posts table. subcategory will be displayed in the dropdown menu and after the user selects the option the subcategory id should save in posts table as a foreign key. why in getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'subcategory_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `Posts` (`question`, `description`, `solution`, `image`, `tags`, `subcategory_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (nn, nm, nkl, 14095989_1298359046904580_8427689213294994369_n.jpg, nlknl, , 5, 2017-12-29 07:32:51, 2017-12-29 07:32:51))

The Subcategory_id is not passing.How to solve it?

**Create():**

```
  public function create( Postqs $postqs, Subcategory $sub_cate)
  {
    $sub_cate = DB::table('subcategory')->pluck("sub_cate","id")->all();
      return 
   view('postqs.create',compact('users','categories','sub_cate_id'));
}
```

**Store()**

```
  public function store(Request $request, Subcategory $sub_cate)
   {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'question' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'tags' => 'required',
    ]);
    $user = auth()->user();
     $data = $request->all();
     $data['user_id']=$user->id;
     $data['subcategory_id']=$sub_cate->id;
  return redirect()->route('postqs.index');
```

}

**Blade:**

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="subcategory_id" class="col-md-2 control label">Category</label>
          <div class="col-md-6">
           <select class="custom-select col-md-10" name="subcategory_id" id="subcategory_id">
            @foreach($categories->sub_cate as $subcategory_id)
               <option value="{{$subcategory_id}}">{{$subcategory_id->sub_cate}}</option>

             @endforeach

     </select>             
            </div>
              </div>
```

**postqs Model:**

```
protected $fillable = 
    ['question','description','solution','image','tags','user_id'
   ,'subcategory_id'];
```

Comment: Please update your question with the `store()` method where you saving form data to DB.

Comment: done @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: You're not creating (inserting) anything in the `store()`. Please show the code which generates the query you've shown.

Comment: i dont get it..

Comment: you're not working with DB in the `store()` method. Please show the code where you trying to insert data into the table.

Comment: @kavi , please post the code snippet in which you try to insert your data.

Comment: You're missing a whole bunch of inverted commas. I suggest you start with something simpler